# How to limit network bandwidth apt-mirror

Tags: networking, bandwidth, apt-mirror

I am setting up a local repository server and downloading the repository takes up to lots of internet bandwidth. How do I limit the apt-mirror to download with 2MB/s?
Internet connection has become 300ms slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to another question over on ServerFault, apt-mirror has this ability built-in. Just add the following line of code to your mirror.list file:

```
set limit_rate 50k
```

The answer also states that the limit is per thread, so if you have 10 threads, the limit would be 50k * 10 = 500k. It also appears that the setting is in KiloBytes/s instead of KiloBits.

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/88780/how-can-i-limit-the-bandwidth-of-apt-mirror